# Populating Array from Another Array in a For Loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am in the process of creating a health monitor based on the output of a logfile.txt. I'm reading the entire log into an array, then working the array within a for loop.

```
var txtFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
txtFile.open("GET", "EarLog.txt", true);
txtFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (txtFile.readyState === 4 && txtFile.status === 200) {
        allText = txtFile.responseText;
        lines = txtFile.responseText.split("\n");
    }

    var i = 0;
    var name;
    var status;
    for (i = 5; i < 31; i++) {
        var res = lines[i].split(": ");
        name = res[0]
        status = res[1];
    }

    document.write("<br>" + name[1] + "<br>")

}
txtFile.send(null);
```

And here is the part of the log file that I am reading from.

```
"Checkout Started at 14:52:11.57 :: Fri 07/24/2015"
StarTeam 11.0 Command Line Interface, Build 11.0.0.82
Copyright (c) 2003-2009 Borland Software Corporation. All rights reserved.
Using ini file: C:\ProgramData\Borland\StarTeam\ConnectionManager.ini
Folder: deployment  (working dir: C:\Deployment\EARS\FutureRelease)
servicing.ear: skipped
portal.ear: checked out
.
.  
.
communications.ear: checked out
"Checkout Completed at 14:54:11.63 :: Fri 07/24/2015"
```

However, instead of name being populated with the name of each ear, it is being populated by each individual letter of the last line read, in this case communications.ear so when I try to write something like

```
document.write(name[10])
```

instead of displaying the tenth ear, it displays the tenth letter of the last ear read. The same issue also occurs for status. Basically I want to be able to call the variable name[1] and have it show the string "portal.ear" and call the variable status[1] and have it show the string "checked out", and so on.

Comment: Try putting document.write call within for loop.

Comment: When I do that, it works fine. But I need to be able to manipulate the output outside of the for loop. the document.write call is really just for debugging purposes, so I can see what it is printing in an internet browser.

Answer (score 1):

Change the code block to:

```
var i=0;
var name = [];
var status = [];
for (i = 5; i < 31; i++) { 
var res = lines[i].split(": ");
name.push(res[0]);
status.push(res[1]);
}
```

Basically, you are storing value in a variable not in array, so when you call name[10] it actually refers to String variable not String[].

Answer (score 1):

The variables `name` and `status` are strings, not arrays.  So when you try to access the nth element, you get the nth letter.

If you want them to be arrays, change:

```
var name;
var status;
```

to:

```
var name = [];
var status = [];
```

Then fill the arrays using the push method. Change:

```
name = res[0]
status = res[1];
```

to:

```
name.push(res[0]);
status.push(res[1]);
```

Then you can refer to the strings stored in the name/status arrays as name[10], status[23], etc.